# SSH into remote Ubuntu Virtual Machine using VS Code, with a username of my choice, not the currently logged in Windows user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, visual-studio-code

My local computer with Windows 10 OS is the machine I'm lunching VS Code on, to connect to my Virtual Machine running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

On my local computer with Windows 10 OS I'm logged in as `spinn`, which becomes the default login for SSH connection lunched from VS Code, which is not the login I need for this SSH connection.

It looks like that:
[image: ![enter image description here]

Following this video: [https://youtu.be/GEA4t1Z1OP4][2]
I've created `config` file in `.ssh` folder on my local Windows 10 machine.

It looks like this:

```
Host 172.105.88.119:????          # I've changed my port number into ????, because I didn't want to share it here.
  HostName 172.105.88.119:????    # I've changed my port number into ????, because I didn't want to share it here.
  User shrek
```

Despite specifying user name in this `config` file, VS Code still populates user for SSH connection as `spinn`, which is the user name I'm logged in on my local Windows 10 computer.

There was never any dialog box to choose the user name I want to SSH as.

There is no **`spinn`** user on remote Ubuntu Virtual Machine I'm logging into. And I don't want to create **`spinn`** user there.

I need to use **`shrek`** user to log into this remote Ubuntu Virtual Machine.

Where can I specify this user name in VS Code?

**EDIT**

After applying @LSerni comment advice and @Nikita Kipriyanov answer, my Windows 10 `.ssh/config` file looks like this:

```
Host 172.105.88.119
Hostname 172.105.88.119
Port ????
User shrek
```

And it works fine.

Comment: Try specifying just the host, without the port: `Host 172.105.88.119`. Also, I am not sure whether HostName is case sensitive and spelled 'Hostname'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.ssh/config` syntax is wrong.

The `Host` clause shoud not have any port and it should match the name you are specifying *exactly*.

The `HostName` also doesn't use any port. There is additional dedicated `Port` option to specify it:

```
Host 172.105.88.119
    Port ????
    User shrek
```

Notice, I didn't specified any `HostName` because it is inferred from the connection.